# how to debug the cause of problem using pear mdb2

Tags: php, pear, mdb2

```
<?php

 include("PEAR/MDB2.php");
      $dsn = 'mysqli://root@localhost/heart_hugger';
$options = array(
    'debug' => 2,
    'result_buffering' => false,
);

$mdb2 =& MDB2::singleton($dsn, $options);
if (PEAR::isError($mdb2)) {
    die($mdb2->getMessage());
}


$table_name = 'cms';

// if left as a non array all fields of the table will be fetched using '*'
// in that case this variable can be set to true, to autodiscover the types
$result_types = "";

$mdb2->loadModule('Extended');
$res = $mdb2->extended->autoExecute($table_name, null,
                        MDB2_AUTOQUERY_SELECT, 'cmsId = '.$mdb2->quote(1, 'integer'),
                        null, true, $table_name);

if (PEAR::isError($res)) {
    die($res->getMessage());
}

$row = $res->fetchRow();
echo "value from fetchrow = ".$row[2];


$mdb2->disconnect();
?>
```

i am getting the following error

> MDB2 Error: not supported

and i have no idea what exactly is not supported. The above code is an example given by pear in MDB2 manual. can any one please suggest what i am missing ? thanks

Comment: Which of the `die()` calls gives you the not supported error? Also, what does `$res->getUserInfo()` tell you?

Comment: thanks for the reply i am running it on localhost with only user root

Comment: can you please tell me how to check which of the die() call ?

Comment: MDB2 Error: not supported checkResultTypes: [Error message: cms for 0 is not a supported column type] [Last executed query: SELECT * FROM cms WHERE cmsId = 1] [Native code: 0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, debug which of the die calls are echoing the message:

```
die('first: ' . $res->getMessage());
```

After that, check the extended user information:

```
die($res->getMessage() . "\n" . $res->getUserInfo());
```

This should give you a hint about the real problem.

Comment: this is what i am gettingMDB2 Error: not supported checkResultTypes: [Error message: cms for 0 is not a supported column type] [Last executed query: SELECT * FROM cms WHERE cmsId = 1] [Native code: 0]

Comment: Seems the `autoExecute´ parameters do not match what the API says. Check it with http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/docs/2.4.1/MDB2/MDB2_Extended.html#methodautoExecute

Comment: thanks i have fixed it the docs are abstract some one need to inherit them and provide more details...thanks @cweiske.